# ActionBar ShareActionProvider does not open on clicks

Tags: android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-optionsmenu

i add the ShareActionProvider to one of my Fragments Options menu:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/options_share_forecast"
    android:actionProviderClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@share_forecast"/>
```

I see the Action Item with correct Share Icon, but i cant click open it. First i throught this could be a problem using a wrong intent. But this seems not the cause. Also looked in the Samples from ActionBar Sherlock. And i copy and pasted most code just to ensure i nit miss any small piece there. Still no luck. The difference i see there is that the sample **ShareActionProviders** inherit from SherlockActivity but mine is an **SherlockListFragment**

My ListFragment onCreate looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            ...
```

I test this on my Nexus 10, no emulator with plenty of APPs installed.

So what i miss there ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some deeper research i stumpled over [this Bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41960&q=ShareActionProvider&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars). If i simply remove

```
  mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName("some_custom_history_name.xml");
```

i can click the Menu as expected! Or u have to swap method calls.